# Isekai manga with a girl who travels to a world where there are only girls

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember is that the main character is a girl who goes to school, new start I believe.

She gets isekai'd into another world. It might have been seamless.

The world has only girls and it's a romance manga, I believe.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Did the girl inhabit her own body in the other world, or someone else's? And can you tell us a bit more bout the other world? For example, what time period was it set in?

Comment: Parallel Paradise has only girls but the MC is a male.

Comment: It was non fantasy I believe and school based. I don' recall much but I think it was normal time. the world is basically all girls now and I believe the girl had a crush on a guy beforehand but now is in an all girls world. she also meets a person the first day whom would be the romantic partner most likely. It was black and white, the girl inhabited her own body, and that's mostly what I remember. light art style not too detailed I believe but take that with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The Whole of Humanity Has Gone Yuri Except for Me](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-whole-of-humanity-has-gone-yuri-except-for-me)*. It is licensed by Yen Press.

> Marika Juuno has somehow ended up in **world where only women exist** -- which she discovers one morning when she sees two girls kissing each other on the way to school!

Marika is a normal high school student; it's not a new start, as she's going to her usual high school, just in a new world. As mentioned in the question, it's a seamless isekai. Marika has no idea she's in a different world until she notices affection between women, and a complete lack of men.

I don't see any mention of her having a crush on a boy, however the introduction states that she's "in love with [the] normal", i.e. she wanted a "normal" life with no excitement and no isekai'ing where she'd just work,  get married, have kids, etc.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag `Single-Gender Society`.

Comment: AAAA THANK YOUUUUU, I'm 99% sure this is it. Has that soft art style I remember, and the first few pages seem oddly familiar. I dunno how good or bad this manga is but I've been on the edge due to forgetting about it for a couple years now so this makes me feel much better. I did not expect this to work out this well ahah, thank you!!

Comment: @きいろ You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).